# CGImage from portrait UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

Trying to figure how image is being rotated or flipped when one gets `cgImage` from `UIImage` which is in portrait mode.

I.e. if I have a case, where `image.size.width < image.size.height` and then call `let cg = image.cgImage!`, I get `cg.width > cg.height` (in fact, `cg.width == image.size.height && cg.height == image.size.width`). I know about the difference in coordinates for `CGImage` and `UIImage`, but what I don't understand - which corner of `UIImage` is taken as the origin for `CGImage` and whether image is flipped somehow?

This messes up with my cropping code, where I simply calculate cropping rectangle for `UIImage` but then trying to crop image by calling `image.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)` gives me unexpected results (wrong area is cropped). Does `rect` need to be in `CGImage`'s coordinate system? I tried flipping it like this, but it doesn't help either:

```
swap(&croppingRect.origin.x, &croppingRect.origin.y)
swap(&croppingRect.size.width, &croppingRect.size.height)
```

Comment: UIImage, like all things UIKit, uses the upper left corner as the origin. That much I know. :-) Also, I *believe* the only thing that uses anything else as their origin is CoreImage, which uses the lower left. As for rotation, two things: (1) UIImage has an *imageOrientation* property that may cause some images to automatically rotate in a UIImageView. (2) There was at least one question asked in the last 10 days with a Swift tag that may help you out. Last, I was having issues - so far not resolved - with cropping cgImages like yours'. I went in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

For those, who might run into similar problems as I did, I post this Swift playground code, which helped me understand what's going on and how to tackle it:

```
import UIKit

let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "down.JPG")!
image.size
image.imageOrientation.rawValue

let center = CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0.3)
let kx = (center.x > 0.5 ? (1-center.x) : center.x)
let ky = (center.y > 0.5 ? (1-center.y) : center.y)
let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width*kx, height: image.size.height*ky)
// cropRect is defined in UIImage coordinate system
// it is defined as a rectangle with center in "center", with proportions
// to the original image. size of rectangle is defined by the distance from 
// the center to the nearest edge divided by 2
// this was chosen due to my specific needs and can be adjusted at will 
// (just don't exceed limits of the original image)
var cropRect = CGRect(x: center.x*image.size.width-size.width/2,
                      y: center.y*image.size.height-size.height/2,
                      width: size.width,
                      height: size.height)

cropRect

if self.imageOrientation == .right || self.imageOrientation == .down || self.imageOrientation == .left
{
    let k : CGFloat = (self.imageOrientation == .right ? -1 :(self.imageOrientation == .left ? 1 : 2))
    let dy = (self.imageOrientation == .right ? self.size.width : (self.imageOrientation == .left ? 0 :self.size.height))
    let dx = (self.imageOrientation == .down ? self.size.width : (self.imageOrientation == .left ? self.size.height : 0))
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: k*90/180*CGFloat.pi)
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: dx, y: dy)
    cropRect = cropRect.applying(rotate).applying(translate)
}

let cgImage = image.cgImage!
cgImage.width
cgImage.height

cropRect

let cropped = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect)

if cropped != nil
{
    cropped!.width
    cropped!.height

    let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cropped!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

}
```

Take 4 pictures: "up.JPG", "down.JPG", "left.JPG" and "right.JPG" for all possible camera configurations and upload them to the *Resources* subfolder of your playground. Load them one by one and check what's happening to the arguments. This code helped me to come up with the working solution: **when image has `.right` or `.down` orientation, apply affine transforms to the cropping rectangle in order to get desired cropping**.

Comment: Up voted. Good job using *.imageOrientation*. I found that something not mentioned most places.